# Disable the double tap zoom functionality for an swf converted ion HTML 5 using Swiffy

Tags: html, flash, mobile, zooming, google-swiffy

I have a little flash game I am converting using swiffy.

In it, a little ant moves when you click some on screen buttons.
However whenever you click the button quickly it fires up the double tap zoom functionality of the mobile device.

Is there a line of code I can add to the HTML that will disable the double tap zoom on that page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on the `<head>` section of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

That should do the trick.